# How can i refresh a xaml page with WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i want to refresh a xaml page with wpf but i dont know how can i do this...

I can't do this :

```
NavigationService?.Navigate(new MainWindow());
```

i've try this one :

```
this.NavigationService.Refresh();
```

but still not working can you help me ?

Comment: What does refresh mean? If you mean have the inital viemodel values you could just attach a new vm to the page or wipe your current vm clean (or set it to the initial state whatever you want to call it)

Comment: I just want to refresh my page. when you use : NavigationService?.Navigate(new MainWindow());

well I would like to have the same result on my xaml.cs file

Comment: if you want to know this is my method i use on my xaml.cs file
`private async Task UpdateFirstName(string lastFirstName, string newFirstName)
        {

            await _context.UpdateDBFirstName(lastFirstName, newFirstName);

            this.NavigationService.Refresh();
}`
I would like that at the end of my method the xaml page refresh

Comment: What does xaml page refresh mean??? If the viewmodel is empty your view should be "clean" or "refreshed" or whatever

Comment: Pages retain user input @EpicKip. That's one of the reasons to use viewmodel first navigation with user controls instead of pages. Pages come with some side effects. Try explicitly setting keep alive false on your page.

Comment: should be "refreshed"

Comment: @Andy But if the value is 2 way bound and the vm becomes empty shouldn't the values (user input) be cleared as well?

Comment: Pages can retain state. They are a nuisance.

Comment: @Andy Any idea on how or why when data is bound? I've personally never had this issue which is why I don't understand because conceptually it shouldn't happen (in the situation i described)

Comment: Viewmodel first and datatemplates allow you control  over your views. It's a common pattern https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-and-tricks-using-contentcontrol-instead-of-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx

Comment: @Andy @ EpicKip I can’t understand what you’re talking about, but putting my builder’s proptieties back at the end of my method doesn’t pose any problem. But I cannot use `NavigationService?.Navigate(new ViewPage(my prorieties));`

Comment: maybe i should have to make a button "refresh" with this code on : `NavigationService?.Navigate(new ViewPage(my prorieties));`

Comment: hum... i found a solution of my probleme :) i've do this : `NavigationService?.Navigate(new ViewPage(firstname, lastName, password, username, mail));`

i dont know why before it was not working